# Max memory for 21" 2007 iMac?

Tags: imac

Have a 2007 21" imac. friend installed 2, 4GB memory for me, Apple genius says that's what causing slow downs on my machine? when they tested it only had a 4GB & a 2GB cards, so someone along the way did a switch on me. Apple says my machine can only handle 4GB total. i wonder if that's true? seems like it ran quite well for a long time, & it used to corroborate that it had 8 GB memory, so something fishy has occurred. machine is running quirky & would like to have max memory. Would appreciate some knowledgeable input...

Answer (score 1):

[Crucial, UK](http://uk.crucial.com/gbr/en/compatible-upgrade-for/Apple/imac-%28mid-2007%29%23memoryResults) state that 4GB is the maximum amount of RAM that your iMac officially supports.

If you put more in and it worked then this could be seen as a 'bug', and wouldn't be supported by Apple. Such abilities could also be revoked through software/firm was updates.

Comment: true and not true, mine has max 4gb supported by apple 8gb actual. i upgraded ram around 6 years ago and I've not had any issues and the system makes use of all

Comment: I’m failing to see what part of what I said could be seen as not true 

Comment: i meant that the 4gb is not the maximum... which is just what you said. i missed that... my mistake

i simply ment that the mac he has apparently supports more than that!

Answer (score 0):

according to Mactracker the mid 2007 imac 20inch has:
Maximum Memory  6.0 GB (Actual) 4.0 GB (Apple)
Memory Slots    2 - 200-pin PC2-5300 (667MHz) DDR2 SO-DIMM

you should also make sure that you always have the same amount on both slots in your case two 3gb however 3gb rams are rare therefore more expensive

Comment: Are you saying you have a iMac (20-inch, Mid 2007) with two 4 GB 667 MHz DD2 SDRAM memory modules and OS X reports your total memory is 8 GB?

Comment: no i have a later model, what i am saying is that the max set by apple is not neccerly the real maximum the computer supports. and according to mactracker the 20 inch mid 2007 supports 6gb

Answer (score -1):

In another forum some users have confirmed 2007 iMac works with 8 GB with no issue after the el Captain upgrade.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different.  We like answers to be more than just a single line.  Ideally, you want to explain why your answer is *right.*  It also helps to provide links, citations, and/or screen shots.  Please review our help section [How to Answer](http://apple.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer) on writing good answers to questions